# Alphabetical paginate gem error

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, pagination

I have deployed the alphabetical_paginate gem on my dictionary rails app (https://github.com/lingz/alphabetical_paginate). The gem works apart from the fact that when I click on a letter it gets stuck on the loading wheel and does not paginate until I refresh the page.

I can only presume this is a javascript problem inside the gem and not the way I have implemented it?

Controller:

```
class WordsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @words, @alphaParams = Word.all.alpha_paginate(params[:letter], {:default_field => "all"}){|word| word.word}
  end
```

View:

```
<%= alphabetical_paginate @alphaParams %>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Word</th>
      <th>Wordtype</th>
      <th>Description</th>
      <th colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

<div id="pagination_table">
  <tbody>
    <% @words.each do |word| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= word.word %></td>
        <td><%= word.wordtype %></td>
        <td><%= word.description %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', word %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</div>
</table>
```

Comment: when posting questions try to be more inquisitive, what have you tried to solve the problem?

Comment: look at server and browser logs, maybe there is an error message there

Answer (score 0):

You should change you call to:

@words, @alphaParams = Word.all.alpha_paginate(params[:letter], {:default_field => "all", :js => false}){|word| word.word}

alphabetical_paginate uses an ajax feature when js: true, This will cause the page to reload with the correct results. Also I don't think you can have

```
<div id="pagination_table">
```

in the middle of a table.